# JSON Array not returning data

Tags: android, json

I have this JSON data and Im having problem to extract data for my weather app. Im getting JSONexception and I dont know why

```js
{
  "city": {
    "id": 792680,
    "name": "Belgrade",
    "coord": {
      "lon": 20.46513,
      "lat": 44.804008
    },
    "country": "RS",
    "population": 0,
    "sys": {
      "population": 0
    }
  },
  "cod": "200",
  "message": 0.0106,
  "cnt": 9,
  "list": [
    {
      "dt": 1437944400,
      "main": {
        "temp": 17.99,
        "temp_min": 17.99,
        "temp_max": 20.44,
        "pressure": 1013.8,
        "sea_level": 1024.97,
        "grnd_level": 1013.8,
        "humidity": 60,
        "temp_kf": -2.45
      },
      "weather": [
        {
          "id": 800,
          "main": "Clear",
          "description": "sky is clear",
          "icon": "01n"
        }
      ],
      "clouds": {
        "all": 0
      },
      "wind": {
        "speed": 2.41,
        "deg": 347
      },
      "rain": {
        
      },
      "sys": {
        "pod": "n"
      },
      "dt_txt": "2015-07-26 21:00:00"
    },
```

My method for extraction look like this.

```
private void renderWeather(JSONObject json) {
    try {

        String precipitation = "N/A";

        JSONArray listObjects = json.getJSONArray("list");
        for (int i = 0; i < listObjects.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject JSONobj1 = listObjects.getJSONObject(i);

            DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
            String time = df.format(new Date(json.getLong("dt") * 1000));

            if (JSONobj1.getJSONObject("rain").length() != 0) {
                precipitation = JSONobj1.getJSONObject("rain").getString("3h");
            }

            String temperature = JSONobj1.getJSONObject("main").getString("temp");

            int weatherIconId = JSONobj1.getJSONArray("weather").getJSONObject(0).getInt("id");

            HourlyForecast hourlyForecast = new HourlyForecast(time, precipitation, temperature, weatherIconId);
            hourlyForecastArrayList.add(hourlyForecast);


        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("SimpleWeather", "One or more fields not found in the JSON data");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No JSON data found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here is the exception.

```
 org.json.JSONException: No value for dt
        at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
        at org.json.JSONObject.getLong(JSONObject.java:477)
        at com.slobx.slobodan.weathermob.Tab3.renderWeather(Tab3.java:107)
        at com.slobx.slobodan.weathermob.Tab3.access$000(Tab3.java:31)
        at com.slobx.slobodan.weathermob.Tab3$1$2.run(Tab3.java:89)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

at this line

```
String time = df.format(new Date(json.getLong("dt") * 1000));
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the exception?

Comment: Use  `e.printStackTrace();` in `catch` block and see what exception exactly you get

Comment: You are catching a generic exception, so I have no idea what type of exception is being thrown.  Please change your log statement so the full exception is logged.      Log.e("MYAPP", "exception", e);

Comment: @lostintranslation here is exception

Comment: @Slobodan Vrhovac at which line of code your getting the exception in the for loop or before

Comment: @has19 in loop at this line String time = df.format(new Date(json.getLong("dt") * 1000));

Comment: @Slobodan Vrhovac  try getting the first jsonobject from listObjects and than access  the variable dt through it

Comment: Again, if you just post the exception stack trace the answer will reveal itself.

Comment: @has19 No matter what position I get same exception

Comment: @Slobodan Vrhovac try listObjects.getJSONObject(0) ,it should work and you can't loop through all the jsonarray since the variable dt is only avialable in the first jsonobject of listObjects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you use `json.getString(" dt")` instead of `JSONobj1.getString("dt")`

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was easy :D

Answer (score 0):

Probably some positions of `list` array might not have `dt` property defined.

Before using the values make sure if they exist using `json.isNull("dt")` or use optString(), etc. These methods won't throw any exception but will return null or 0 instead.

Comment: All positions in array have dt filed because it is Date/Time parameter and it is compulsory and I check them manually just to be sure

Comment: @SlobodanVrhovac, for the exception thrown at the line you posted it doesn't seemed so. Are you absolutely sure you always have a `dt` field?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [Gson library](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide). Gson makes this kind of stuff really easy.

All you need to do is define POJOs for each Json object in your json file. You don't need to write any code to convert to JsonObject/JsonArray, Gson handles that for you.

The POJO classes should be defined with the same names as the json keys, and with appropriate datatypes (your json structure could probably use some refactoring).

```
class CityInfo {
    City city;
    String cod;
    double message;
    int cnt;
    List<Info> list;
}

class City {
    int id, population;
    String name, country;
    Coord coord;
    Sys sys;
}

class Coord {
    double lon, lat;
}

class Sys {
    int population;
}

class Info {
    long dt;
    String dt_text;
    Main main;
    Weather weather;
    Clouds clouds;
    Wind wind;
    Rain rain;
    Sys2 sys;
}

class Main {
    double temp, tempMin, tempMax, pressure, seaLevel, grndLevel, humidity, tempKf;
}

class Weather {
    int id;
    String main, description, icon;
}

class Clouds {
   int all;
}

class Wind {
    double speed;
    int deg;
}

class Rain{}

class Sys2 {
    String pod;
}
```

Once you've defined the POJOs properly, you can convert between json-string <-> POJO like this:

```
// Build a gson object responsible for conversion and set naming convention
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
    .setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES)
    .create()

// Convert from json-string to POJO
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.json"));
CityInfo cityInfo = gson.fromJson(br, CityInfo.class);

// Convert from POJO to json-string
String json = gson.toJson(cityInfo);
```